# Обработка определённой кнопки из таблицы

Tags: php

Нужно занести значение в функцию. Сгенерил таблицу с кнопками, в которых записано ИМЯномерстроки ("D1", "D2".."Dn").
Кнопки могут добавляться и удаляться. Нужно как-то обрабатывать эти кнопки и узнавать какую строку надо удалить.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Lab4 - Cookies</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\\main.css">
    <link rel="script" href="script.js">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="modal">
    <label class="btn" for="modal">Додати студента</label>
    <form class="popup" method="post">
        <span>Введіть дані студента</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ім'я" name="studentName">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Прізвище" name="studentSurname">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Група" name="studentGroup">
        <input type="submit" class="addStudent" value="Додати студента" name="addStundent">
        <label class="close" for="modal">+</label>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="table">
    <form method="post" class="table-form">
        <?php

        if(isset($_POST['addStundent']))
            addStud();
        if (isset($_POST['D']))
        {}
        displayTable();
        function addStud()
        {
            $name = corrector($_POST['studentName']);
            $surname = corrector($_POST['studentSurname']);
            $group = $_POST['studentGroup'];
            //echo $name . " " . $surname;
            $filename = "students.txt";
            $file = fopen($filename, "a+");
            fwrite($file, $name.";".$surname.";".$group.";"."\n");
            fclose($file);
        }

        function displayTable()
        {
            $filename = "students.txt";
            $file = fopen($filename, "a+");
            if(filesize($filename) == 0)
                return 0;
            $fit = fread($file, filesize($filename));
            echo "<div id='source'><center><caption align='center'>Студенти</caption></center><table cellspacing='0' align='center'>"."<br>";
            echo "<table cellspacing='0' align='center'>";
            $str = $fit;
            for ($i = 0; $i < substr_count($fit, "\n"); $i++) {
                echo "<tr>";
                for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
                    $pos = strpos($str, ";");
                    $arr[$i][$j] = substr($str, 0, $pos);
                    $str = substr($str, $pos + 1, strlen($str));
                    echo "<td><input disabled value='" .$arr[$i][$j] . "'></td>";
                }
                echo "<td><input type='submit' name='" . "D". $i . "' value='-'></td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            fclose($file);
        }

        function corrector($str)
        {
            $str = preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", $str);
            $pos = strpos($str, ' ');
            if($pos != 0)
                $str = substr($str, 0, $pos);
            //setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "ru_RU.CP1251");
            $str = translit($str);
            $first = ucfirst(substr($str,0,1));
            $last = strtolower(substr($str,1,strlen($str)-1));
            $str = $first . $last;
            return $str;
        }

        function translit($str) {
            $rus = array('А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'І', 'Ї', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я', 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я');
            $lat = array('A', 'B', 'V', 'G', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'Zh', 'Z', 'I', 'Y', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'F', 'H', 'C', 'CH', 'SH', 'SCH', 'Y', '\'', 'I', 'YI', 'Y', 'E', 'YU', 'YA', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'zh', 'z', 'i', 'y', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'h', 'ts', 'ch', 'sh', 'sch', '', 'y', '\'', 'e', 'yu', 'ya');
            return str_replace($rus, $lat, $str);
        }
        ?>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Страница с кнопками]

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Оформите код через песочницу, при редактировании вопроса нажмите Ctrl+M.

Comment: Вариантов реализации - миллион. Например добавить на каждый `tr` атрибут `data-id` в который писать номер строки или `id` записи из БД (не знаю откуда Вы получаете данные). По нажатию на кнопку `удалить` в такой строке через `javascript` получать этот `id` и с помощью `ajax` отправлять запрос на сервер с его указанием, где `php`-скрипт уже удалит данные из БД или файла, где они там у Вас лежат... Ну и при успешном ответе от сервера о удалении - удалять строку и на странице.

Comment: Спасибо. Добавил в form input нашёл кнопку
`<script type="application/javascript">
            var list = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
            var out;

            function delStudent(target){
                var index;
                out = document.getElementById('hidden').innerHTML;
                for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
                    if(list[i] == target) index = i;
                }
                document.getElementById('hidden').value = index;
            }
        </script>`
кинул индекс в **input** и обработал нажатие кнопки через PHP.